# Filling empty cells - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, is-empty

I'm trying to fill empty cells in a specified range. I have used code taken from other questions to write this:

```
Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In ws.Range("E36:G45")
    If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) = True Or IsNull(rCell.Value) = True Or rCell.Value = "" Then
    rCell.Value = -999
    End If
Next rCell
```

This doesn't work, neither does the following (where the Boolean is removed):

```
For Each rCell In ws.Range("E36:G45")
    If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) Or IsNull(rCell.Value) Or rCell.Value = "" Then
    rCell.Value = -999
    End If
Next rCell
```

The range E36:G45 contains a mix of empty and non-empty cells.

I have tried clearing the contents.

There are no sub procedures that could make the cells un-editable.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error - the code works fine for me. Are you ***sure*** those cells are empty?

Comment: You do have `ws` declared and assigned a value right?

Comment: The latter would fail as the reference to an implicit condition would not be determined.  As for your assessment, try `If len(rng) = 0 then` in lieu of your checks?

Comment: @Warcupine - absolutely :)

Comment: Try adding condition for `Trim(rCell.Value) = ""`

Comment: @CLR - yep, definitely empty. I cleared contents and checked with =IF(ISBLANK).. and showed they are empty.

Comment: @dbmitch - I tried but no luck!

Comment: @Cyril - Am I right using `len(rng)` like this:

`For Each rCell In ws.Range("E36:G45") 
If len(rCell) =  0 Then` ...

Comment: If `=IF(ISBLANK)` is showing the cells blank, then your code should work. Indeed, it works fine here. So - is it possible that the worksheet you're looking at, and the worksheet (`ws`) the code is looking at - could be different?

Comment: @CLR - That's a good idea but not the case. This code is part of a huge sub-process that creates a report for a selected worksheet. There are loads of other things happening that mean the correct worksheet must be being referenced by the sub. I'll ask the creator of the worksheet and see if I can find out some more information about how the cell values are generated (either input by hand or by another module...). Thanks to everyone so far for your great answers!

Comment: This is not reproducible given the info you've shared so far. Some other detail is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try simplifying your criteria; you can use `len()` combined with `trim()` to help with this, which will give your results as either `0` or `>0`:

```
dim cellRef as range
for each cellRef in ws.range("E36:G45")
    Select case len(trim(cellRef.value))
        Case 0
            cellRef.value = -999
    End select
Next cellRef
```

---

Edit1:  Updated per Ben's comment;

Comment: Why not just do `Case 0`, `cellRef.value = -999`.

Comment: @BigBen - There could be cells in my range that are correctly input as 0 that I wouldn't want to change

Comment: @obrunt - this is checking that the *len* is 0, not that the cell value is 0. I'm commenting on the `Case >0`, `Case else`, which can be simplified.

Comment: @BigBen very true; i had paired down this code from a larger set where i was showing each of his cases and didn't update the final case (had 4, including Else).

Comment: @Cyril, yeah makes sense. Regardless, this is a typo-type question (sheet was protected, per an answer that OP has since deleted).

Comment: @BigBen - It isn't! I was convinced it was that the sheet was protected but that's not the case!

Comment: Not a typo-type question!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the code is looking at a different worksheet - I suspect it's writing those -999s elsewhere.

If I were doing this, I'd use the following code:

```
Sub Fill_empty_cells()
On Error Resume Next
ws.Range("E36:G45").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = -999
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

This definitely fills in cells that have been cleared using ClearContents.

That said, your original code does that also, hence my theory it's not looking at the same sheet you are.

To fully debug what's going on though, why not create some commentary so you read what's going on:

```
Sub test()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each rCell In ws.Range("E36:G45")
        If IsEmpty(rCell.Value) = True Or IsNull(rCell.Value) = True Or rCell.Value = "" Then
            rCell.Value = -999
        Else
            Debug.Print "Not filling cell " & rCell.Address & " of sheet [" & rCell.Parent.Name & "] because it contains """ & rCell.Value & """"
        End If
    Next rCell
End Sub
```